# Firebase Database Rules - rules based on custom claims

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a firebase realtime database. Currently it contains two nodes `admin` and `common`

```
{
  "admin" : {
    "adminval" : 9898574632,
    "adminval1" : 645354536,
    "adminval2" : 7776756433
  },
  "common" : {
    "commonval" : 123433221
  }
}
```

I added to each user custom claim `roles` which describes roles user has in my system. It looks like this

```
{'roles': ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER']}
```

Now I would like to restrict access so only users with claim `ROLE_ADMIN` are allowed to read/write `admin` node and with either of the roles can read/write node `common`.

How to do it ? I tried something like it:

```
{
    "rules": {
       "admin": {
           ".read": "auth.token.roles.contains('ROLE_ADMIN')",
           ".write": "auth.token.roles.contains('ROLE_ADMIN')"
       }
       "common": {
           ".read": "auth.token.roles.contains('ROLE_USER') || auth.token.rules.contains('ROLE_ADMIN')",
           ".write": "auth.token.roles.contains('ROLE_USER') || auth.token.rules.contains('ROLE_ADMIN')"
       }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid we cannot use `Array` or `List` in Realtime database security rules. Language of rules can work with only limited set of types. You can check the documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database.

We can walk around this limitation for instance by using `String` in claims:

```
{'roles': 'ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER'}
```

Now we can check the appropriate role using

```
".read": "auth.token.roles.contains('ROLE_USER') || auth.token.rules.contains('ROLE_ADMIN')"
```

, because `String` supports `contains` method. Another option, as you suggest in your comment, is to set claims like

```
{'role_admin': true, 'role_user': true}
```

and then check the role in rules

```
".read": "auth.token.role_admin == true || auth.token.role_user == true"
```

Side note: we can use `List` and `in` operator in Firestore security rules, see doc here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used arrays in custom claims, so am not sure how that works, or why it doesn't work for you.

But I did notice that you're doing a weird mix of role-based access control and level-based access control in your rules, so want to give some general hints/observations:

- You're marking your admins with both roles: `ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_USER`.
- But then you have an OR in the `common` node, checking for either role. This means there's no need to give the admin the `ROLE_USER` too.
- Keep in mind that custom claims are limited to 1000 bytes and are sent with every request. I'd highly recommend dropping the `ROLE_` prefix, since that's already implied in the `roles` name of the claim.
- If you have a universal logic that admins can see more than regular users, consider using a numeric `access_level` claim instead. Say a regular user is `level: 1`, while an admin is `level: 2`. You can then in your claims check for the minimum level: `".read": "auth.token.access_level >= 1"`

Comment: thanks for your points I'll think about them - anyway the example in my question it's just some abstract case - the real question is: Can I use array in custom claims ? Why the `contains` method doesn't work ? I want to have role-based access and a user can have multiple roles and I want to avoid having claim for each role like `{panelAdmin: true, otherPanelAdmin: false...` - what is the best approach to such case ?